# kotlin how to refer outer-scope this in multi-layer apply functions

Tags: lambda, kotlin, apply

for example:

```
 v1?.apply {
       v2?.apply {
           call(this, target, outerThis);
       }
    }
```

my question is how to refer to "outerThis"? 
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use a [label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) and then a [qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) expression:

```
v1?.apply outer@ {
    v2?.apply {
        call(this, target, this@outer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this work on an extension function as well?
In my case, I'm extending a function on the `java.util.Date` class. inside my function I was thinking about calling `Calendar.getInstance().apply {` and I could not figure out how to get a reference for my Date object.

Answer (score 10):

It's generally not recommended to use nested `apply` calls, which is to avoid your situation. You may of course use labels as a workaround, but you may also use `also` as an alternative:

```
v1?.also { outer ->
    v2?.apply { 
        call(this, target, outer)
    }
}
```

This prevents the usage of a label, which is often frowned upon. <sub>There is nothing wrong with labels though.</sub>

Note: `also` is a new addition to the stdlib in kotlin 1.1. If you are using older version you may not be able to see it. Either update kotlin to 1.1 or add this piece of code anywhere in your module:

```
inline fun <T> T.also(block: (T) -> Unit) { block(this) }
```