# How to refer to outer this on forEach in Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I have the following case

```
someThing.forEach{
    someWidget.setOnClickListener{
        //it is an View
        //I need foreach it of someObject
    }
}
```

I read this answer but it does not work

> [kotlin how to refer outer-scope this in multi-layer apply functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779568/kotlin-how-to-refer-outer-scope-this-in-multi-layer-apply-functions?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not dealing with `this` here.

`forEach` has a parameter and for simplicity you can leave it away and just use `it` instead. Not using it is the same as using `_ ->` instead... you just discard it.

So your example written with named lambda parameters instead:

```
someThing.forEach{ some -> // 'it' was available here too, but will not be accessible from within the next setOnClickListener...
  someWidget.setOnClickListener{
    // some contains one of the someThings now and 'it' is still your View
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name the variable in the forEach.

```
things.forEach { thing ->
    someWidget.setOnClickListener {
        thing.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
someThing.forEach{ x->
    someWidget.setOnClickListener{
        //use x
        //I need foreach it of someObject
    }
}
```

just use another name like `x`, you don't have to use `it`.
Here is an example:

```
val a = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 3)
val b = mutableListOf<Int>(2, 4)

a.forEach { x ->
    b.forEach {
        println("" + x + " " + it)
    }
}
```

here `x` is each item from list `a`  
and `it` is each item from list `b`